# State not get updated as expected in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am dynamically adding few attributes to objects on a array in vuex store. I am watching the state change and once it changed, I run a method which will add the attributes as needed.

```
watch: {
      todayMeetings(newMeetingList, oldMeetingList) {
        //alert();
        this.addLine(newMeetingList);
      }
    }

addLine(newMeetingList) {
        var isFirst = true;
        for (var meeting of newMeetingList) {
          var nowTime = new Date();
          var meetingTime = new Date(meeting.meetingTime);

          if ((nowTime.getTime() < meetingTime) && isFirst) {
            meeting.isLine = true;
            meeting.isLast = false;
            isFirst = false;
          } else {
            meeting.isLine = false;
            meeting.isLast = false;
          }
        }
        if (isFirst) {
          newMeetingList[newMeetingList.length - 1].isLast = true;
        }

      },
```

This all works fine and I see the changes in `</template>`. But I need to run the addLine() method in every 5 sec. So I used it inside a setInterval function as follow,

```
setInterval(function () {
        console.log('Mounted');
        this.addLine(this.storeMeetings);
      }.bind(this), 5000);
```

I called it inside mounted, but its not updating the store as I expected.
my full script is as follow,

```
<script>
  import { mapState, mapActions, setState } from 'vuex';
  import todayMeetingItem from './todayMeetingItem.vue';
  import todayMeeting from './todayMeeting.vue';
  import { BIcon, BIconCalendar3, BIconChevronLeft, BIconChevronRight } from 'bootstrap-vue';
  export default {
    props: ['selectedPartner'],
    components: {
      todayMeetingItem,
      BIcon,
      BIconCalendar3,
      BIconChevronLeft,
      BIconChevronRight,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        organizationId:'',
        today: new Date(),
        todaymeeting:[],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      createMeetingEmit() {
        this.$emit('createMeetingEmit');
      },
      ...mapActions('meeting', [
        'getTodayMeeting'
      ]),
      deleteMeeting(meeting) {
        this.$emit('meetingWasDelete', meeting);
      },
      addLine(newMeetingList) {
        var isFirst = true;
        for (var meeting of newMeetingList) {
          var nowTime = new Date();
          var meetingTime = new Date(meeting.meetingTime);

          if ((nowTime.getTime() < meetingTime) && isFirst) {
            meeting.isLine = true;
            meeting.isLast = false;
            isFirst = false;
          } else {
            meeting.isLine = false;
            meeting.isLast = false;
          }
        }
        if (isFirst) {
          newMeetingList[newMeetingList.length - 1].isLast = true;
        }

        console.log('newMeetingList');
        console.log(newMeetingList);
        this.$store.commit('setTodayMeetings', this.storeMeetings);
        console.log(this.storeMeetings);
        console.log('this.storeMeetings');

      },
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapState({
        storeMeetings: state => state.meeting.todayMeetings
      }),
      ...mapState({
        storeUpcomingMeetings: state => state.meeting.upcomingMeetings
      }),
      ...mapState({
        mettingLoading: state => state.meeting.meetingLoading
      }),
      todayMeetings() {
        return this.storeMeetings
      }
    },
    mounted: function () {

      this.organizationId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('organizationId'));

      this.getTodayMeeting(this.organizationId);

      //this.addLine(this.storeMeetings);

      setInterval(function () {
        console.log('Mounted');
        this.addLine(this.storeMeetings);
      }.bind(this), 5000);

    },
    watch: {
      todayMeetings(newMeetingList, oldMeetingList) {
        //alert();
        this.addLine(newMeetingList);
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you expect to happen vs what is actually happening just by looking at this code but I can tell you for sure that if you set your store to use [strict mode](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html), you will see many warnings about altering state outside of a mutation

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will find my answer useful.
If I get you right, you are trying to alter the store but it's not working ?

### Short answer

use your method `addLine` only when the store value changes with the `watch`

### Some quick notes:

- avoid mutating the state from the components
- avoid mapping the state, use state getters instead
- not a good idea to have the an interval just to update the template from the values from the store. **There is a way to do a computation when the state machine (store) change**

PS: I am available for 15min so that we can pair program on this.